# How to put several files in one archive?

Tags: windows-7, email, archiving, attachments

I have 10 files which I need to send per e-mail. It is inconvenient for me all 10 files and it will be inconvenient for the receiver to download all 10 files (it can be annoying to do the same operation 10 times).

I would like to put all 10 files into one files (I think it can be done as archive). How can I do it?

**Important details.** I am working in the Windows 7 and prefer to do the mentioned operation from the command line. In the directory, where I have my 10 files, I have many other files which I would not like to include into the archive. The files are small, so compression rate and size do not play any role. I just one to have an easy way to put 10 files into one and then easily to extract these 10 files.

Answer (score 5):

7zip would do the job.

With 7zip you can create a .tar archive, .zip, or a .7z archive.

And you can create self-extracting zip executables, in case the recipient doesn't know what to do with a .tar or .gz file.

I would recommend you get 7zip and RTFM as to how to use it on the command line.

Comment: And its FREE - big plus!

Answer (score 0):

Download and install [FreeZIP](http://members.ozemail.com.au/~nulifetv/freezip/). Put the 10 files you want to archive in a new directory (for example "zip"), make right-click on the folder and select "zip". 
7zip will create a .zip archive named Free.zip. Send this to your receiver. He needs to install Freezip or an other archive-manager that can handle zip. 
I think Windows itself can allready unpack zip-files. But I am not shure about that because I always used WinZip and/or Winrar (not free).

Answer (score 0):

Use a command line compression tool. [Info-Zip](http://www.info-zip.org/) is one free one that I've use quite a bit.

Answer (score -1):

Locate the file or folder that you want to compress. Right-click the file or folder, point to **Send to**, and then click **Compressed (zipped) folder**. A new compressed file is created in the same location. You may rename it as you wish.

Comment: -1 he was asking for command-line solutions

Comment: Since I think this is a simple and quick solution, I've posted this answer. This way he won't have to install a 3rd party app (like 7zip) to archive the files.